# Is putting business logic inside listener/executer classes a bad practice?

Tags: java, oop

When using frameworks such as messaging queues (RabbitMQ, etc) or scheduling frameworks (Quartz, etc.), there is a need to implement some of the framework's interfaces (`Job` interface or `MessageListener` interface). It's a common practice to avoid putting any business logic inside the implementations, and delegate immediately to some other class. For example:

```
class MyJob implements org.quartz.Job {
    private MyDelegate delegate = new MyDelegate();

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        String arg = context.getMergedJobDataMap().getString("arg");
        delegate.run(arg);
    }
}
```

From OO perspective, it makes sense because of the Single Responsibility principle. But other than that, it just leads to class bloat, and overly layered code.

Is there any practical benefit to delegation?

Comment: I vote for keeping it separate (a good bit because it allows for Dependency Injection, should such be used). I would be more interested in finding an 'automated way' (generic type, reflection proxies, etc.) to avoid having to create such 'bloated' Job types manually, but would leave it at that.

Comment: do you need DI for MyJob ? I hope people are not gonna test MyJob with mocked delegate and context, to verify the two lines of code in execute()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good thing about principles is that there are so many of them.

In your case, I'd go for simple, direct implementations. 
There's no need to extract business logic now; we can always do that later when  needed.

Comment: agreed.  Later, if you find that piece of business logic is being duplicated in other parts of the system, extract it out then.

Answer (score 1):

A practical benefit of delegation is that you can reuse your business logic if you ever need to switch to a different framework / queue / interface / whatever, or if you need to add another one in addition to the current one (e.g. you're exposing your business method as a web service but want to add a REST API).

Comment: @bayou Opinion-based :)

Comment: It can be quantifiable. And in many cases, it's provable that it's wasteful to design against future events with low likelihood.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you should be spending little time as possible in callbacks. For example in Android, spending too much time in UI callbacks (run in UI thread) will block your application.

From Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html):

> Specifically, if everything is happening in the UI thread, performing long operations such as network access or database queries will block the whole UI. When the thread is blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events. From the user's perspective, the application appears to hang. Even worse, if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog.

Comment: Was this for a different question? This question appears to be related where to put the code, not in which context to run the (delegated or not) code.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm using Android as an example for code run in listeners. Where to put the code and in which context it is run is linked.

Comment: The *context* in which the operation is run has no immediate bearing on *where* the code to run is located - be it from a delegated object/method, inline with the event handler, in a private method within the same class, within an anonymous type..